# Best approach: trigger or workflow?

Tags: automation

I have a Service Invoice object with a field for due date and one for payments made (as well as total cost/remaining).

If 30 days pass from the due date, 1.5% interest should be added.

I thought to make a workflow with duedate.addDays(30) and checking it with TODAY, but I couldn't find any correct documentation for adding the days.

I thought maybe I could add a new field that has the due date + 30 days, but then I'd have to edit for all existing, and there are over 2000, so I thought maybe there's a better way.

I considered a scheduled (daily) run of a class, but querying could go over limits, if there are over 100 records overdue -- which is possible. I could do a mapping to avoid this, but I felt like building that was more work than I had to do, still feeling like there should be a clear-cut way to achieve this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Time based Workflow with Due Date+30 and in condition check `payments made` is false.

Then you can run this Workflow on record creation. But for the old records you can write a one time script and run that from developer console and update Amount.

As per updated requirement you can use [Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm). You can schedule this batch to run daily and calculate difference between days and if its match you criteria Simply add the interest.

Comment: Can you go into more detail with the workflow? Like I said, I couldn't find much on syntax for adding days. Does +30 automatically add days?

Comment: In addition, what do you mean by "on record creation"? I haven't done much with scheduled tasks, do you mean any time ANY record is made, it checks? Once at the beginning of each day would suffice....

Comment: As far as updating the rest, recall the governor limits. Wouldn't querying for them all go over?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis yes +30 will automatically add days. When we Create a WF we get option to decide when this workflow will run so where you can select. In one shot you can update 10000 records so you can set the limit.

Comment: I did a lot of it and I'm realizing now I don't think the timing will quite work. I don't want just one time 30 days after. I want every 30 days thereafter to ad 1.5 percent of the unpaid...

Comment: >  I don't want just one time 30 days after. I want every 30 days thereafter to ad 1.5 percent of the unpaid... 
Then you have to modify your question - this kind of requirements are playing a huge role on what to choose.

Comment: yes as Oleksiy mention @NatalieSpatharakis you should mention this in initial requirement for this Batch is the most suitable solution. You can write a batch who will run daily and add interest whenever applicable.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much to you both! To close off this question, might you refer to me a source of documentation that will help with this? I'm not familiar with the functionality you're referring to, but I don't need to continue that on this question :)

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Answer updated.